# Android: Open a Website by a click of a button

Tags: android

I want to open a website by a click of a button in my android app.

I have already tried

```
Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"));
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
startActivity(intent);
```

And It works.

But the problem is that whenever I open any website which does not have `"https://"` in the url, the app crashes. 
e.g.

```
 Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("www.google.com"));
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
    startActivity(intent);
```

the app crashes after this.

Please help me what to do in this case.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: why don't you add `https://www.` before the link if it doesn't have ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to launch a link in the chosen browser in User's Phone

```
/**
 * Function to launch a default URL
 */
private void launchURL() {

    try {
        Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");

        /**
         * Why the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK is needed
         * http://stackoverflow.com/
         * questions/3689581/calling-startactivity-from
         * -outside-of-an-activity
         */
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        i.setComponent(ComponentName
                .unflattenFromString("com.android.chrome/com.android.chrome.Main"));
        i.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
        i.setData(Uri
                .parse("http://www.google.com"));
        startActivity(i);

    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        // Chrome is probably not installed
        Intent i = new Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try the function I pasted, does it not work?

Comment: No, the program didn't work. 
The same problem is happening with it that it is not able to point to "www.google.com" unless "https://" or "http://" prefix is added to it.

Comment: I apologize. It is working. A small mistake from my side was happening.

Comment: @Neferseti - If the answer helped, mind marking it as the answer?

Answer (score 3):

You may check the case manually!

```
if (!url.startsWith("https://") && !url.startsWith("http://")){
    url = "http://" + url;
}
Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(intent);
```